# Trouble aligning a div

Tags: css, html

I'll admit from the outset that I'm a self-semi-trained hack when it comes to html and css.

The problem I need help with is a **drop down menu** that is **not centering** in the container div. I need to have the menu behave like the one in the live site http://wedevents.com.au/index.htm

PROBLEM PAGE EXAMPLE: http://www.wedevents.com.au/index.asp (it's a work in progress so please forgive the mess)

Thaks for any help!
Regards,
Rick

Comment: you want to center the drop down?

Comment: Any code to help decipher? You want the drop down centered? or disappear when moving away from that drop down menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you want the links across the top to be centered on the page?

Floating the ul left won't help that :p. On ul.topnav, remove float:left and change the following properties:

```
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 85px;
width: 630px;
height: 36px;
```

Comment: We have a winner! As soon as I saw you mention the left float, I knew to try yours first :-) Thanks Christain!

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust the width on your `.topnav` and adjust the `padding` as well.

Then on your `ul.topnav li ul.subnav` add this `left:-31px;` this shall make your drop down center below the weddings option

Answer (score 0):

Create another div that will contain your ul class=topnav, set the width that fit in the page wrapper and add this as the property of ul:

> margin: 0 auto;